# Can't take and show data name from session login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i wanna make some login page and then show the user name in the dashboard after login succeed. But the name won't show in the dashboard. its just blanks.
there's no error notification or something.
please help. thanks

I'm running on PHP 7

---

### Auth.php Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email',
        'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['title']='Login Page';
        $this->load->view('templates/auth_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
        $this->load->view('templates/auth_footer');
    }
    else{
        //success validation
        $this->_login();


    }

}

private function _login()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $user = $this->db->get_where('user',['email' => $email])->row_array();

    if($user){
        //user active
        if($user['is_active']==1){
            //check password
            if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
                //if pass were right
                $data = [
                    'email' => $user['email'],
                    'role_id' => $user['role_id']
                ];
                $this->session->set_userdata('$data');
                redirect('user');

            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> Wrong password</div>');
                redirect('auth');
            }

        }
        else{
        //
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
            Email has not been activated</div>');
        redirect('auth');

    }

    }
    else{
        //no email in database
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
            Email is not registered</div>');
        redirect('auth');

    }

}
```

### User.php in controller (control for user)

```
public function index()
{

    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user',['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
    $data['title']='Dashboard - SmartStock';
    $this->load->view('user/index', $data);
}
```

and command for showing the data in page

### index.php

```
  <div class="navbar-menu-wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">

    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-right">
      <li class="nav-item nav-profile dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="profileDropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="nav-profile-img">
            <img src="<?= base_url('assets/'); ?>images/profile/default.png" alt="image">
            <span class="availability-status online"></span>             
          </div>
          <div class="nav-profile-text">
            <p class="mb-1 text-black"><?= $user['name']; ?></p>
          </div>
        </a>
```

Comment: did you debug it in index() with print_r($data);die;? are you getting user data in `$data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your mistake is Here in Auth->_login() line `set_userdata`,
replace

```
$this->session->set_userdata('$data');
```

with

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```